# Need help in pattern matching in Perl

Tags: regex, perl, pattern-matching

How to do the pattern match of "Iface Name: bnx2i.00:17:a4:77:14:2f" exactly? There should not be spaces or new lines before and after.

Comment: How much of this do you need to match?  What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
my $if = "Iface Name: bnx2i.00:17:a4:77:14:2f";
if ($if =~ /^Iface Name: ([a-f0-9]+\.(?:[a-f0-9]{2}:){5}[a-f0-9]{2})\z/) {
   print $1;
}
```

Comment: The code allowed spaces and newlines after the text, which the OP specifically forbad. Fixed.